# Creating number of elements by variable - not by array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to duplicate image element (representing correct/wrong answers) by an observable and not by array. can this be done?
(see location marked in XXXXXXXXX). 
answerCorrect and answerfailed are updated elsewhere.

JS:

```
var singlePhase=function (phaseNo,questionsTotal)
{
    var self=this;
    self.phaseNo=phaseNo;
    self.answersTotal=questionsTotal;
    self.answerCorrect=ko.observable(0);
    self.answerfailed=ko.observable(0);
}

var QuestionViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var tmpArrPhases = new Array(); 
    tmpArrPhases.push(new singlePhase(1,2));
    tmpArrPhases.push(new singlePhase(2,2));
    tmpArrPhases.push(new singlePhase(3,3));
    self.allPhases(tmpArrPhases);
}
```

in HTML I want to do:

```
        <div data-bind="foreach: allPhases">
            <div class="progress_bar_bottom_mustry" data-bind="foreach:XXXXXXXXX">
                <img src="images/correct.png" data-bind="visible:true">
                <img src="images/wrong.png" data-bind="visible:true">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty array inside `foreach` binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: allPhases">
    <div class="progress_bar_bottom_mustry" data-bind="foreach:new Array(YourObservalbe())">
        <img src="images/correct.png" data-bind="visible:true">
        <img src="images/wrong.png" data-bind="visible:true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7UDfM/